# Need to update my cookies from flash cookies but without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, flash

I am storing some information into Flash cookies. when anyone hitting a page it first check for m/c cookie and then it checks for flash cookie. If the flash cookie has some extra information it is writing on the m/c cookie but it is **refreshing** the page again, which in-turn increasing my page count/ view.

I want my m/c cookies to be updated by flash cookies as soon as user gets the response. I **don't want to refresh the page again** which is causing by flash cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Edit/Update your cookies via javascript.

Comment: can you guide me how can i do that....I am not aware of that..any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check the Actionscript docs and read about the ExternalInterface which will allow you to communicate with Javascript. Practically, whenever you want to access a JS function from AS3 , you could use ExternalInterface to call it.

It's not clear in your description what causes a page refresh, reading a Flash cookie wouldn't cause that. Send us more information if ExternalInterface doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have this question as well... Flash runs client side, which means, in order to set a PHP session, server-side, you need atleast run the flash application in the client to get the flash cookie value and than pass that value to php. That is what is meant with the refresh.